# observing two children from a database in swift from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there an effective way to observe two nodes at once from firebase? Could you write sample code for it if possible?

Comment: If you know how to observe one node, then you know how to observe two nodes - it's exactly the same code. See the Value Events section here [Retrieving Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data)

Answer (score 1):

Put call for the second node in the completionBlock of the first one:

For example i have my user's location coordinates(lat and lng) stored in two node's stored under my UserId:-

```
ref.child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("latitude").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(SnapshotLAT) in

      ref.child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("longitude").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(SnapshotLNG) in
  .....
..... 
  })
})
```

Maybe i could help you more if you posted your JSON structure here....